# Input not rerendering inside SimpleForm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, renderer, admin-on-rest

i was using AOR 1.2.2 for site settings panel.
Tricky part was that those settings can have different types: string,int,bool, array of string, int etc
I managed to do this by connecting record from store and using this code:

```
const SettingsEdit = (props) => {
  return (
    <Edit actions={<SettingsEditActions {...props} />} title=
      {<SettingsTitle />} {...props}>
      <SimpleForm toolbar={<EditToolbar />}>
        <TextField source="description" />
        <DisabledInput elStyle={{ width: '100%' }} label="Default 
         value" source="defaultValue" />
        {renderCountryValue(props)}
      </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
  );
};




const renderCountryValue = (prop) => {
  const record = prop.record;
  if (record) {
    if (record.multilang) {
      // countryValue will be a dict with locale keys
      // TODO Multilang fields temporary disabled in restClient
      return null;
    }
    // countryValue will be single value or array
    if (record.schema.type === 'array') {
      // countryValue will be single array
      if (record.schema.items.type === 'string') {
        return <LongTextInput format={v => v.join()} parse={v => v.split(',')} label="Value" source="countryValue" />;
      }
      if (record.schema.items.type === 'integer') {
        return <LongTextInput format={v => v.join()} parse={v => v.split(',')} validate={validateIntegerArray} label="Value" source="countryValue" />;
      }
    }
    // countryValue will be single value
    if (record.schema.type === 'string') {
      return <TextInput label="Value" source="countryValue" />;
    }
    if (record.schema.type === 'integer') {
      return <NumberInput label="Value" source="countryValue" />;
    }
    if (record.schema.type === 'boolean') {
      return <BooleanInput label="Value" source="countryValue" />;
    }

    return <LongTextInput label="Value" source="countryValue" />;
  }
  return <TextInput label="Value" source="countryValue" />;
};
```

It was working well untill i tried updating AOR to 1.3.1 then it stopped.
What i noticed is that in first render there is no record so it renders default TextInput but on second render when there is record it doesn't rerender this Input into correct type like NumberInput or etc.
I tried to debug it and programm come to place when it should render other Input but nothing happen on screen.
Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Have faced some issues myself when depending on record in props. I usually then set manual checks for the value and return null when no record is found in props.